# How to browse RMI server disk file system with java.io.File?

Tags: java, client-server, rmi, file-listing, filelist

I want a RMI server / client system where you can browse the files on the server with a client. In this case the server is a Debian and the client runs on Windows.

I tried to have the server hold a `File` object pointing to the currently seen directory and show all files in that directory in a `List` on the client.

The problem is, when I call a method returning me `file.listFiles()`, I don't get the files on the server but on the client or `FileNotFoundException` as if the server would run on the client. The Java `File` API seems to use the root directories on the computer where the client runs on and not the server.

Simpler said: I want a file explorer on the client showing me the server file system.

Edit:

```
public class ClientMain {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        }
        View view = new View();
        view.setVisible(true);
        try {
            String name = "Remote";
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1");
            IRemote model = (IRemote) registry.lookup(name);
            view.setModel(model);
            view.update();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Remote Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public class View extends JFrame implements IView{
    JList list;
    IRemote model;
    public View() {
        super();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        list = new JList();
        this.add(list);
    }
    public IRemote getModel() {
        return model;
    }
    public void setModel(IRemote model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public void update(){
        try {
            this.list.setListData(model.getFileList());
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


public interface IRemote extends Remote {
    public String[] getFileList() throws RemoteException;
}

public class Model implements IRemote{
    File current;

    public Model() {
        super();
        current = new File(".");
    }

    public String[] getFileList() {
        return current.list();
    }

    public void setCurrentDirectory(String current) {
        this.current = new File(current);
    }




}
public class ServerMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ServerMain();
    }

    public ServerMain() {
        super();
        Model model = new Model();
        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        }
        try {
            String name = "Remote";
            IRemote stub = (IRemote) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(model, 0);
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            registry.rebind(name, stub);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Controller exception:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

This is what i am trying to do. Here the Server binds a Model to the Registry. The Client looks up the Model give the Model to the View and the view calls getFileList() from the Model. With the "." File I get the Directory where the Programm is located. Since it's relative I get all the File on the Client where the Client Programm is running. If I use a non-relative Directory I get the FileNotFoundException because the Client does not have this path. Hope that makes it even clearer.

Comment: What have you gotten so far? It seems as you need a few of the remote filesystem and some stubs that can expose this over rmi. Do you only want to show the structure or do you also need to implement functionality for delete, view content, move, rename etc?

Comment: The RMI part is already implemented the Problem is really that I can't see the Files on the Server. It's as if the Programm would be run locally. Delete functions etc. are the next step. I figure if I can get the Files I can use those pretty easily.

Comment: If you are not getting the server files then I'd say the rmi part is not implemented ;-) Can you show what your implementation and stub looks like?

Comment: So i edited the Question to show a simple Example of my Problem.

Comment: By the Way could this be the same Problem I see when printing something on the specific Consoles? If I add a printout in the Model here in the given Example, the Printout appears on the Client Console not the Server Console. Of course only when the Method is called by the Client.

Comment: You don't show how you start the server. I assume you have the rmiregistry on your local (windows) machine. I just made a very simple implementation which works here (between a Solaris and an OSX) machine. What is you start as simple as possible, just command line to fetch and print the files?

Comment: The Rmiregistry is on the Linux Server. The Clients makes his lookup on that Server to get the Remote Object.

Comment: In this simple example both run on the same Machine but there is no Problem running the Server on a different Host. And I added the ServerMain It seems I forgot that Part.

Comment: If I remove the SecurityManager on the client that works for me. Which jam version are you using. Exactly how are you invoking this? On the server I start rmiregistry and the the ServerMain. On the client I changed the "127.0.0.1" to point to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File` is not a remote object. Whatever it tells the server applies at the server. You can ship it to the client via RMI as it is serializable, and it doesn't take any external state with it such as the state of the server's file system.

Comment: Since that seems to be the Problem. I started transferring only the Filenames. Thanks now I know why i would'nt display the Files.